# JSON data against DeepSee MDX queries in InterSystems Caché

Tags: json, mdx, olap, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I want to retrieve JSON data against MDX queries on DeepSee OLAP cubes in InterSystems Caché. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MDX2JSON](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/Cache-MDX2JSON) project for that. It's RESTful web api for MDX2JSON transformation (also JSONP and XML/A). Also supports requests about Pivots, Dashboards and Widgets. Supports Caché 2014.1+.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any demos?